# How does ajax push work?

Tags: ajax, push

In simple terms, how is push achieved through ajax? Is this done through the same object used for conventional ajax requests?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> In simple terms, how is push achieved through ajax?

The general idea is to always have a request to the server "hanging", so the server can respond to it whenever it wants to "push" something to the client.

> Is this done through the same object used for conventional ajax requests?

It can be, but you can emulate it with an `iframe` as well. This field is in very active development currently, so maybe [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSockets) and the [EventSource](http://dev.w3.org/html5/eventsource/) should be mentioned here as well.

Answer (score 3):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) has a simple definition of the Comet model, used to make AJAX push work

Answer (score 2):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Ajax

It might be the standard in HTML5

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events

Answer (score 1):

A simple logic is to get updateds from the server after a prefixed time interval. Usually this is done by setInterval() method of javascript and the jquery ajax is used to check the server database. You can visit this URL http://tinytute.com/wordpress/2013/08/02/create-a-simple-jquery-php-based-push-notification/